# SQLAlchemy: Can I hash password in a User class that's a declarative_base class?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, werkzeug

I have the User class:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost/academic', convert_unicode=True, echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)

class User(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['user']

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')
    
    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
    
    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)
```

The code works fine without the password methods, but once i uncomment them the page keeps loading and no response is coming from the server.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `self.password` inside the `@password.setter`, causing an infinite recursion. Take a private field `_password`, and have that correspond to where the data is written to and read from:

```py
class User(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['user']
    _password = Column("password", String(256), nullable=False)

    @property
    def password(self):
        raise AttributeError('password is not a readable attribute')
    
    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self._password = generate_password_hash(password)
    
    def verify_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self._password, password)
```